# landsat-util zip files

Tags: python, landsat

I've just started using landsat-util and am having a couple of problems. First of all, the standard download command only downloads Bands 4,3,2 (the visible bands) and the QA band. In the docs it says it should be downloading a zip file of all bands. EG:

```
(venv)XXXXXX:landsat XXXXX$ landsat download LC81720352015321LGN00
===> Downloading: LC81720352015321LGN00_B4.TIF
   100%     65.1 MiB     374.9 KiB/s            0:00:00 ETA     
     stored at /Users/XXXX/landsat/downloads/LC81720352015321LGN00
===> Downloading: LC81720352015321LGN00_B3.TIF
   100%     64.5 MiB     348.1 KiB/s            0:00:00 ETA    
     stored at /Users/XXXX/landsat/downloads/LC81720352015321LGN00
===> Downloading: LC81720352015321LGN00_B2.TIF
   100%     64.3 MiB     490.8 KiB/s            0:00:00 ETA    
     stored at /Users/XXXX/landsat/downloads/LC81720352015321LGN00
===> Downloading: LC81720352015321LGN00_BQA.TIF
   100%      2.7 MiB     563.9 KiB/s            0:00:00 ETA    
     stored at /Users/XXXX/landsat/downloads/LC81720352015321LGN00
===> Downloading: LC81720352015321LGN00_MTL.txt
   100%      7.4 KiB       7.4 KiB/s            0:00:00 ETA    
     stored at /Users/XXXX/landsat/downloads/LC81720352015321LGN00
===> Download Completed
===> Done!
Time spent : 523.64 seconds
```

If I try to download any other bands directly I get an error:

```
(venv)XXXXX:landsat XXXXXX$ landsat download LC81720352015321LGN00 -bands 8
usage: landsat [-h] [--version] {search,download,process} ...
landsat: error: unrecognized arguments: 8
```

I've tried this with several tiles, all with the same result. I know these files are being downloaded from AWS, but I believe that I should be getting the full zip, not individual bands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `landsat-util` downloads the full ZIP archive if the scenes you request are from before 01-01-2015. Everything after downloads the bands you requested. ([source](https://pythonhosted.org/landsat-util/overview.html#a-note-on-returned-products))
2. You are adressing the bands wrong. Your command should use either `-b` or `--bands` e.g. `landsat download LC81720352015321LGN00 -b 8`
3. Sadly there is no `-b all` option. A feature I hope developmentseed will implement in the future.

Comment: Sorry I didn't receive notification of this reply, but it's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not know Landsat-utils well.

But if you only need to download LANDSAT tar.gz archives, you might try using [LANDSAT-download](https://github.com/olivierhagolle/LANDSAT-Download).